# Bad substitution error in terminal related to bash profile

Tags: bash, terminal

I get this error when I open terminal

```
-bash: JAVE_HOME=${/usr/libexec/java_home}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Also misspelled `JAVE_HOME`(`JAVA_HOME`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't have `${...}` around the pathname. The line in your `.bashrc` or `.profile` should be

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/libexec/java_home
```

Also, you misspelled `JAVA` as `JAVE` (unless that's a copying error).